# Difference between 'File.Open()' and 'new FileStream()'

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

What's the difference, if any?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

None.

`File.Open()` is, internally, nothing more than:

```cs
public static FileStream Open(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
{
    return new FileStream(path, mode, access, share);
}
```

If you don't use the overload which specifies a `FileAccess` and `FileShare`, it specifies this for you (using `FileShare.None`, and `FileAccess.Write` on append or `ReadWrite` otherwise).

That being said, this is an implementation detail, not part of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx). Technically, a future .NET Framework release *could* use a different implementation, although I find that unlikely.

Comment: So, there is a difference - I just ran into: Sharing is different by default.

Answer (score 26):

This kind of duplication is very rare in the .NET framework.  But there's a story about this one, told by Krzysztof Cwalina in [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lZP2j9bjbU).  They did a usability study on an early version of the framework, asking a bunch of experienced (but otherwise .NET agnostic) programmers to write some code using the FileStream and StreadReader/Writer classes.

It didn't go well, they got a 100% fail rate.  They responded by adding methods to the System.IO.File class, using the "most likely to fall into the pit of success" approach.

Cool video btw, if you're at all into the reasons the framework looks the way it looks.

Better post a real answer: the File.Open() method calls the FileStream constructor, passing values for FileAccess and FileShare (if you don't specify them) that are most likely to do the Right Thing.  Which is FileAccess.ReadWrite and FileShare.None.

Comment: Updated.  Beware it is a 500MB .zip file.

Comment: Link is broken again

Comment: Still broken ;-)

Comment: Updated again, now on YouTube.  Hmm, that's a lot of hassle for an answer that wasn't even selected as the answer and can't get enough votes.  Beware future SO contributors, it is like teenage sex.  Five minutes of fun but you'll support it for the rest of your life.

Comment: And, FWIW, the explanation in question seems to start around 44:00 into the video.

Answer (score 7):

`File.Open()` is a convenience method. Internally it is implemented as:

```cs
public static FileStream Open(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
{
    return new FileStream(path, mode, access, share);
}
```

Comment: ...alongside its siblings File.OpenRead and File.OpenText

Answer (score 4):

You have to be very careful with the answers given here! Because there is a subtle difference depending on the operating system you're using the method in.

It's due to the `FileShare` flag which declines sharing of the current file and opening will fail until the file is closed. The flag can *optionally* be passed to the constructor of `new FileStream(...)`. On Windows machines IOException will always throw, on Linux machines only if the flag is set to `FileShare.None`. This is probably due to the difference in how files are handled on Linux (e.g. you can do crazy things like deleting a file on a Linux OS an still writing to it).

To make your code work on both Linux and Windows machines make sure you're either using the convenience function `File.Open(...)` which automatically sets the `FileShare.None` flag or pass the correct `FileShare` flag to the constructor.

I stumbled across that issue when using the following two versions to open a file:

```cs
var fileStreamSource = new FileStream(uploadFilePath, FileMode.Open);
```

and

```cs
var fileStreamSource = File.Open(uploadFilePath, FileMode.Open);
```

Former sets `FileShare.Read`, latter `FileShare.None`. They're idential on Windows machines but not on Linux machines.

I don't know if thats intentional or a bug. However, it bug me.